# I can't run this code

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}

    \begin{document} 
    The quadratic formula is 
    \\\\
    $x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$
    \end{document}
```

I am running this program using Xelatex but it gives the error in line 3. !undefined control sequence and !Latex error Missing \begin{document}

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? By the way, you should ***never*** use ``\\`` in order to “leave a blank line”, and ``\\\\`` will always end up in an error (No line to end).

Comment: You will have to load `\usepackage{mathtools}` or `amsmath` in front of `unicode-math` (or get rid of the `dfrac`)

Answer (score 2):

`\dfrac` is defined in `amsmath` but never use `\\` to force line breaks:

```
  \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}


    \begin{document} 
    The quadratic formula is 
    \[
    x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
     \]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The OP says the error is at line 3, which makes me suspect `\setmathfont` is the problem; the processing didn't get past `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Now it is giving the same error on line 4
If i remove \usepackage{unicode-math} and \setmathfont{XITS Math} it works fine.

Comment: @Shaheryar the above document worked without error for me, if it fails for you put the entire log in your question in a `{}` code block.